# Javascript Print <li> with data-name

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use JavaScript to generate JQuery ListView,  once I click on the listview item it will show an alert message.

In the demo I found in Stack Overflow it works perfectly.

Once I try to integrate my code with it, it does not work anymore. Is the way I'm generating data-name in my listview is correct?

Sample of my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TLGY7/416/

```
$('#mylistview ul').children('li').bind('click', function(e) {
    var item = $(this).attr('data-name')
    alert('Selected Name=' + item );
});

function view() { 
    if (db==null) {
        alert('Error: Database is null.');
        return;
    }
    $('#listData').empty();
    db.executeSql(
        'SELECT `id`, `activityname`, `location`, `sdate`, `stime`, `reporter` FROM `record` ORDER BY `id` ASC',
        [],
        function(resultset) { 
            var length = resultset.rows.length;
            for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
                $('#listData').append('<li class="activitylist" data-name='+resultset.rows.item(i).id+'><a href="#pageDetail" class="anchor">'+resultset.rows.item(i).id+'.'+stringconverter(resultset.rows.item(i).activityname)+'</a></li>');
            }
            $("#listData").listview( "refresh" );
        },
        function(error) { 
            alert('Error: '+error.message);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `alert('Selected Name=' + item );` is it possible the output is `Selected Name=Object`? you have to get item[0].outerHTML if you want to alert the html code. in console.log you can use the jquery object

Comment: @TypedSource is there is other method that can helps me carry or store the ID as future call data from Database purpose?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TLGY7/12/ @TypedSource this is the original fiddle you might get more idea what i'm trying to do in here

Comment: can you post a sample resulset object please? i cant connect to your database

Comment: Actual result will print sample like "1.Testing". Just simple display object, my objective is to get the data-name inside the <li>. Since i'm setting the table primiry key in data-name so that i can use the value as other data call out purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
var linkElement = $('<a href="#pageDetail" class="anchor">').text(resultset.rows.item(i).id + '.' + stringconverter(resultset.rows.item(i).activityname));
var listElement = $('<li class="activitylist">').attr('data-name', resultset.rows.item(i).id)).append(linkElement);
$('#listData').append(listElement)
```

append method requires JQuery node element, not text

you also can make a $() around your '' statement. the node building itself looks ok for the first view.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i tried ur code it stop function at all.

Comment: is there is other method that can helps me carry or store the ID as future call data from Database purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the listitems dynamically, you should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to handle the click event:

```
$('#mylistview ul').on("click", "li", function(){
    var item = $(this).data('name')
    alert('Selected Name = ' + item );
});
```

In his way the listitems don't have to exist yet when you setup the click handler.

Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TLGY7/419/)**